# VERIFICAATION: Find the 9th term from the end of the AP 5, 9, 13,...., 185.

Tags: proof-verification

Given: AP $\implies$5, 9, 13, ..., 185 
Required: 9th term of AP from last

Solution: Let *a* be the first term, *d* the common difference, *l* the last term 

 We have *d*= a<sub>2</sub>-a<sub>1</sub>=9-5=4

 *d*=4 

 Since *a<sub>n</sub>=a+(n-1)d*

 $\implies$ $ l= 5+(n-1)*4=185 $
     $\implies$  $ 4n-4=180$ 
$\implies$ $n=46$ 
For 9<sup>th</sup> term from last, *n-9=46-9=37*

 $\implies$ 37 is the required term

$\therefore $$ a_{37}=5+(37-1)(4)=144+5=149$

---

But the correct answer turns out to be 153
 where am i wrong?

Comment: You actually want the $38\text{th}$ term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we need $(46-9+1)$th term

But we can use a more direct way:

The $9$th term from the end,

$$185+(9-1)\cdot(-4)=?$$